# How to change color of UITextField in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, colors, uitextfield

I have placed `UITextField` in `UITableView` and my `UITableViewCell` color is Yellow , normally the background color of `UITextField` in white I want to change the color of `UITextField` to yellow or it should be transparent... I have used

```
[txtfld setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

but it's not working - the textfield is appearing in white color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `[txtfld setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];` working?

Comment: no i hav tried this but this is not working then i hav used textview instead using textfield then there is a problem that the cursor going scroll to up side .i hav also set textview.scrollEnabled=NO; can u help me out of this